# create Accord.Video.FFMPEG object intial error

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, accord.net

I create an project with C# Visual studio 2013 and reference Accord.Video.FFMPEG.dll.
The Configure of projects Target Platforms is set to  x86.
It is ok while compileing.
But,It would throw run time error when application running.
The exception is below. showing =>This application cannot be run in 64-bits
I have no idea what wrong with the error?

---

```
System.TypeInitializationException   IsTransient=false
  Message='<Module>' 的型別初始設定式發生例外狀況。
  Source=VideoMarkerAccord
  TypeName=<Module>
  StackTrace:
       於 VideoMarker.Form1.test()
       於 VideoMarker.Form1.ConvertVedio(Int32 iFps, Int32 bitrate, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 iSpeed, String sOutputPath, String xml, String sVCode) 於 d:\Projects\AForge\VideoMarkerAccord\VideoMarker\Form1.cs: 行 201
       於 VideoMarker.Form1.btnConvertVedio_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 於 d:\Projects\AForge\VideoMarkerAccord\VideoMarker\Form1.cs: 行 181
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       於 System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       於 VideoMarker.Program.Main() 於 d:\Projects\AForge\VideoMarkerAccord\VideoMarker\Program.cs: 行 18
       於 System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       於 System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       於 System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       於 System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       於 System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       於 System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       於 System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       於 Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       於 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       於 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       於 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: <CrtImplementationDetails>.ModuleLoadException
       _HResult=-2146233088
       _message=The C++ module failed to load during process initialization.

       IsTransient=false
       Message=The C++ module failed to load during process initialization.

       Source=msvcm90
       StackTrace:
            於 <CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException(String errorMessage, Exception innerException)
            於 <CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException(String , Exception )
            於 <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
            於 .cctor()
       InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
            _HResult=-2146233079
            _message=This application cannot be run in 64-bits.
            IsTransient=false
            Message=This application cannot be run in 64-bits.
            Source=Accord.Video.FFMPEG
            StackTrace:
                 於 _init.{ctor}(_init* )
                 於 ?A0xbe509209.??__E?A0xbe509209@_initializer@@YMXXZ()
                 於 _initterm_m((fnptr)* pfbegin, (fnptr)* pfend)
                 於 <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.InitializePerProcess(LanguageSupport* )
                 於 <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
                 於 <CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport* )
            InnerException:
```